# Can I reuse plastic screw anchor in original position?

Tags: drywall-anchor

Once I put in a screw in drywall with a **plastic screw anchor**, can I remove the screw and replace the screw without ruining the anchor? I saw the answer for the metal anchor but got the sense the answer is different for a plastic one.

Comment: Yes, but it won't hold as much. How much less depends on a lot of un-mentioned and case-specific factors like size of old/new screw, how much it overlaps with the existing thread-carved groves, etc. It's better to replace but if you're hard-up and don't need to rely upon the full weight rating (like for a cheap wall clock or calendar) it should be fine.

Comment: Unless the screw was overtightened the anchor is likely fine. The problem is that a little drywall will crumble away each time you fiddle about with the anchor. Metal anchors, like [Molly bolts](https://hgtvhome.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/hgtv/fullset/2021/9/17/0/shutterstock_ANDY-RELY-1714823422.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.616.411.suffix/1631906133585.jpeg), work by compressing against the back of the drywall. Plastic anchors _usually_ work by [spreading](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1584/7721/files/Plastic-Expansion-Anchor-border-300x200_large.jpg) when the screw is installed, but they do vary.

Comment: [This](https://www.howtogeek.com/319669/how-to-install-drywall-anchors-to-hang-heavy-stuff-on-your-walls/) article provides a reasonable overview of different types of anchors and how they work. There are many more variations available.

Comment: It is called a rawl plug; If you intend to do any home maintenance , buy an assortment, they are cheap.

Comment: I am not admitting how old I was when I found out you could buy new nails; you did not need to pull them out of discarded material and hammer them sort of  straight,